# is possible to work only with a part of a git repository?

Tags: java, git, jgit

i'm developing a desktop app with `JGit` in order to build a cloud system for storing files.

Now, several users contribute to the same repository, but not everyone are interested to work with whole project.

For example, i'm developing with others a software with `MVC` architecture, i just need to access to controller-subdirectory of the project. For that, when i `clone/pull/push` the repository i want just work with the part that i need. I saw the possibility to create submodules or checkout with `git`, but i didn't understand if is the right way for my issue.

Comment: Create new branch in git for it, and merge after you done as feature of application

Comment: I try to help you to find the "shift" key on your keyboard with my downvote.

Answer (score 3):

The simple answer is that you can do it but the long answer is this:

Git store **snapshots** of **ALL** the content of the repo in each commit os if you wish to only use part of it you will basically need to checkout only the desired part that you need and when you commit you will need to have all the content of the current commit.

So again you can do it but you will not gain anything by doing so.

You mentioned that you heard about submodulkes.

---

### **Here is a full explanation about submodule/subtree**

You can try and read about submodules.

> ***`Submodules`*** ***allow foreign repositories to be embedded within a dedicated subdirectory*** of the source tree, always pointed at a particular commit.

---

## ***`git submodule`***

Break your big project to sub projects as you did so far.
Now add each sub project to you main project using :

```
git submodule add <url>
```

Once the projected is added tot your repo you have to init and update it.

```
git submodule init
git submodule update
```

As of **Git 1.8.2** new option `--remote` was added

```
git submodule update --remote --merge
```

will ***`fetch`*** the latest changes from upstream in each submodule, ***`merge them in`***, and ***`check out`*** the latest revision of the submodule.

As [the docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule) describe it:

> ***`--remote`***
>
> This option is only valid for the update command. Instead of using the superproject’s recorded SHA-1 to update the submodule, use the status of the submodule’s remote-tracking branch.

This is equivalent to running git pull in each submodule.

---

> ***However, how would I push a commit in the scenario of bug fix in C which affects the code shared with the parent layers?***

Again: using submodule will place your code inside your main project as part of its content. The difference between having it locally inside the folder or having it as part of a submodule is that in submodule the content is managed (commited) to a different standalone repository.

---

This is an illustration of submodule - project inside another project in which each project is a standalone project.

[image]

---

## ***`git subtree`***

***Git subtree allows you to insert any repository as a sub-directory of another one***

Very similar to `submodule` but the main difference is where your code is managed. In submodules the content is placed inside a separate repo and is managed there which allow you to clone it to many other repos as well.

***`subtree`*** is managing the content as part of the root project and not in a separate project.

Instead of writing down how to set it up and to understand how to use it you can simply read this excellent post which will explain it all.

https://developer.atlassian.com/blog/2015/05/the-power-of-git-subtree/

Answer (score 0):

You can create new branch for it. [Git - Branches](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/using-branches), here is a tutorial.

When you done with your work merge it so every one on the project can see the affect.